# Excel Macro: Print Date when there is a change in data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to have my macro print out the date when my data is updated in column H. Also I need it to print in the same row of the update as well, so assuming I update A2, I want the date to be printed in H2 etc.

I have this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address <> Range("H" & Target.Row).Address Then        
        Range("H" & Target.Row).Value = Date
   End If
End Sub
```

For some reason, when I do end up changing something and hitting enter, I get a small delay, but the date never ends up printing in H. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the issue, but I would add an `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before your IF statement and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` after your END IF.  When I tried to timestamp rows using the `Worksheet_Change` event I got strange results, and sometimes Excel crashed entirely, if I did not include those statements.

Comment: @JoshuaRoss Doesn't seem to help unfortunately. I'm sure I needed them there to begin with though.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what else it could be.  I copied your code with no modifications into Excel and it seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Same with me as @JoshuaRoss.  Is the text color for the cell set correctly and not White perhaps?

Comment: Am I not supposed to create it as a module maybe? Yea I answered my own quesiton. I was making it a module instead of just making it part of the worksheet.@JoshuaRoss

Comment: Worksheet events should be coded in the worksheet, and workbook events should be coded in the ThisWorkbook module.  It seems like you've figured it all out, but in case you're interested [here's a decent article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx) on events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address <> Range("H" & Target.Row).Address Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("H" & Target.Row).Value = Date
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that `Target` is not always a single-cell range, so if you make assumptions that there's only one cell you may find you get unexpected behavior if someone updates two or more cells at the same time...

Comment: Very true! ______________________________________

Comment: @TimWilliams I realize this is very late, but is there an easy way to make it work if the user does in fact change more than one cell? Like have the Date print in every single one of those rows etc

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const DATE_COL As Long = 8
    Dim c As Range

    'don't trigger if user (eg) deletes a whole column!
    Debug.Print Target.Cells.Count
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1000 Then Exit Sub

    On Error GoTo haveError

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each c In Target.Cells
        If c.Column <> DATE_COL Then
            c.EntireRow.Cells(DATE_COL).Value = Date
        End If
    Next c

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```